# c#. How to deserialize this Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

this is my first post :)
I have problem with deserialize json string.
this is example:

```
{
"packs": {
    "category1": {
        "Element1": {
            "url": "Url1",
            "name": "File 1"
        },
        "Element2": {
            "url": "Url2",
            "name": "File 2"
        },
        "Element3": {
            "url": "Url3",
            "name": "File 3"
        },
        "Element4": {
            "url": "Url4",
            "name": "File 4"
        },
        "Element5": {
            "url": "Url5",
            "name": "File 5"
        },
        "Element6": {
            "url": "Url6",
            "name": "File 6"
        },
        "Element7": {
            "url": "Url7",
            "name": "File 7"
        },
        "Element8": {
            "url": "Url8",
            "name": "File 8"
        },
        "Element9": {
            "url": "Url9",
            "name": "File 9"
        },
        "Element10": {
            "url": "Url10",
            "name": "File 10"
        }
    },
    "category2": {
        "short": {
            "url": "Url1",
            "name": "Short "
        },
        "medium": {
            "url": "Url2",
            "name": "Medium "
        },
        "long": {
            "url": "Url3",
            "name": "Long "
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is code deserialize:

```
var json = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url));

var jsonDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.PacksModel>(json.Result);
```

And this is model:

```
    public class PacksModel
{
    public Cathegory packs { get; set; }
}


public class Cathegory
{
    public JContainer category1 { get; set; }
    public JContainer category2 { get; set; }
}
```

I don't have any idea to get data from Element. Any sugest?
Thx for answer !

Comment: your json string is wrong. use http://json2csharp.com/ and see yourself that you are using wrong model

Comment: No, the JSON string is valid. Don't forget the } outside the marking code.

Answer (score 1):

Since category and element names tend to vary, you may be better off defining them as dictionaries:

```
public class PacksModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Item>> packs { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

// ......................................

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacksModel>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.packs["category2"]["medium"].url);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h4BYOE

Answer (score 0):

Try with this objects to deserialize your json:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3.Domain
{
    public class Element1
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element2
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element3
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element4
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element5
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element6
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element7
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element8
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element9
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element10
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category1
    {
        public Element1 Element1 { get; set; }
        public Element2 Element2 { get; set; }
        public Element3 Element3 { get; set; }
        public Element4 Element4 { get; set; }
        public Element5 Element5 { get; set; }
        public Element6 Element6 { get; set; }
        public Element7 Element7 { get; set; }
        public Element8 Element8 { get; set; }
        public Element9 Element9 { get; set; }
        public Element10 Element10 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Short
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Medium
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Long
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category2
    {
        public Short @short { get; set; }
        public Medium medium { get; set; }
        public Long @long { get; set; }
    }

    public class Packs
    {
        public Category1 category1 { get; set; }
        public Category2 category2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Packs packs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And to deserialize it:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonfile = File.ReadAllText("jsonfile.json");
            var deserializedFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Domain.RootObject>(jsonfile);
            // Do something with your object
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your JSON string, your model should look like this:

```
public class Element1
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element3
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element4
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element5
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element6
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element7
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element8
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element9
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Element10
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Category1
{
    public Element1 Element1 { get; set; }
    public Element2 Element2 { get; set; }
    public Element3 Element3 { get; set; }
    public Element4 Element4 { get; set; }
    public Element5 Element5 { get; set; }
    public Element6 Element6 { get; set; }
    public Element7 Element7 { get; set; }
    public Element8 Element8 { get; set; }
    public Element9 Element9 { get; set; }
    public Element10 Element10 { get; set; }
}

public class Short
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Long
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Category2
{
    public Short @short { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public Long @long { get; set; }
}

public class Packs
{
    public Category1 category1 { get; set; }
    public Category2 category2 { get; set; }
}

public class PacksModel
{
    public Packs packs { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var json = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url));
var jsonDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.PacksModel>(json.Result);
```

---

Notice: If you can change the JSON string structure, you should use Arrays for the Elements.

For example, if you change the JSON string structure to this:

```
{
    "packs": {
        "category1": {

            "Elements": [{
                    "url": "Url1",
                    "name": "File 1"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url2",
                    "name": "File 2"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url3",
                    "name": "File 3"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url4",
                    "name": "File 4"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url5",
                    "name": "File 5"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url6",
                    "name": "File 6"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url7",
                    "name": "File 7"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url8",
                    "name": "File 8"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url9",
                    "name": "File 9"
                },
                {
                    "url": "Url10",
                    "name": "File 10"
                }
            ]
        },
        "category2": {
            "short": {
                "url": "Url1",
                "name": "Short "
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "Url2",
                "name": "Medium "
            },
            "long": {
                "url": "Url3",
                "name": "Long "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this model:

```
public class Element
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Category1
{
    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Short
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Long
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Category2
{
    public Short @short { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public Long @long { get; set; }
}

public class Packs
{
    public Category1 category1 { get; set; }
    public Category2 category2 { get; set; }
}

public class PacksModel
{
    public Packs packs { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var json = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url));
var jsonDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.PacksModel>(json.Result);
```

The effort with this JSON string structure is, that you can use a flexible count of elements!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answer.
I'm learning programming in Xamarin.Forms and it's not my json.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var json = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url));
dynamic deserializeJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json.Result);



 private void writeDataOnModelMusicUrl()
    {
        foreach (var part in deserializeJson["packs"]["category1"])
        {

            foreach (var elements in part)
            {
                var url = elements["url"];
                var name = elements["name"];
                //I'm doing something
            }
        }

        foreach (var part in deserializeJson["packs"]["category2"])
        {

            foreach (var elements in part)
            {
                var url = elements["url"];
                var name = elements["name"];
                //I'm doing something
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that's enough :)

The subject can be closed.